# when ajax compleate javascript function not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When my ajax request completes my function is not working.

This is my script:

```
    <script>
     function sendmsg(id,msg){
      alert('id is'+id+'and msg is '+msg);
    }
    <script>

<div class="div1">
  <div id="ajaxreq">

  </div>
<input type="button" onclick="loadmore();" />
 </div>



     <script>
        function loadmore(){
          $.ajax({
             URL:"div1.php",
             data:"act=get",
             type:"GET",
             success: function(data){
          if(data !=""){
               $("#ajaxreq").append(data);
          }
            },
            error: function(data){
              alert("Error Load");
            }
         });
        }
        </script>
```

when data is appended:

```
<div id="ajaxreq">
  <div id="content">
    <img src="./img/1.png">
     <input type="button" onclick="sendmsg("1","Image1");"/> // this is what is want to do//
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using `event` binding on `button` using javascript or jquery then fix your `button` snippet,

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendmsg("1","Image1");"/>
```

To,

```
<input type="button" onclick="sendmsg('1','Image1');"/>
```

EDIT :

In your success ajax handler,

```
success: function(data){
          if(data !=""){
               $("#ajaxreq").append(data);

                  $("#ajaxreq").on('click','button', function(){
                        //add your button click logic
                  });

                  //trigger click on this button
                  //your button dont have any id so do like this..
                  $("#ajaxreq").find("button").click();
          }
},
```

Comment: thanks for answer but its not,this is my sample code.i want call from button  onclick after ajax.

Comment: when using json data how i do it in a loop

Comment: `i want call from button onclick after ajax` how can ajax predict when a button is clicked?